# ASP.NET Core web api editing Bearer auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have the Bearer auth implemented, but I want to make some custom actions in it.
I need to verify, that the claim *token_id* checks out with the token_id in the database. If it does, the request should pass the auth, in the other case, 401 response should be sent back.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/authorization-using-web-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For validating the bearer token, you could custom `OnTokenValidated` like

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {                            
                var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
                var dbContext = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var tags = await dbContext.Tags.ToListAsync();
                context.Fail("Token is invalid");
                return;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! :-)